# How to navigate to parent route (or clear router-outlet)? Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

Let's say that my view looks like that:

**localhost/main**

```
  <h1>Angular Router</h1>
  <nav>
    <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>
    <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

If I click on heroes then URI will be eg. **localhost/main/heroes**

I want to add function in typescript to navigate back to **localhost/main**.

However I don't want to use such a function

```
private navigateToDefaultView() {
    this.router.navigate(["/main"]);
}
```

Since part **/main** might be changed. I'd prefer something like that

```
private navigateToDefaultView() {
    this.router.navigate(ToParentRoute);
// or
    clearRouterOutletSomeHow
}
```

Is it even possible? Or I'm forced to provide URI in string.

---

EDIT:
I came up with something like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.isMainActivated= this.router.url.indexOf("/main") > -1;
        this.isHomeActivated= this.router.url.indexOf("/home") > -1;
}

private navigateToDefaultView() {
        let url;
        if (this.isMainActivated) {
            url = this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.indexOf("main") + "main".length);
        } else if (this.isHomeActivated) {
            url = this.router.url.substring(0, this.router.url.indexOf("home") + "home".length);
        }

        this.router.navigate([url]);
    }
```

But I'd prefer more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was easier than I could imagine.

```
<button [routerLink]="['../']">
   Back
</button>
```

And it returns to parent url.